# Are Android Static References Strong

Tags: java, android, reference, singleton, classloader

I have a singleton that I'd like to keep alive for the lifetime of an [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html).

```
public final class KeepAlive extends Whatever {
    private KeepAlive() {}

    private static class Singleton {
        private static final KeepAlive instance = new KeepAlive();
    }
}
```

Is `Singleton.instance` considered a strong reference, so that it will not get GC'ed?

**UPDATE:** Does Android use a custom classloader? Is so, would it ever unload a class like `KeepAlive` or `Singleton`?

Answer (score 5):

The short answer - yes. Once it's created, it will not be garbage-collected.